# How to copy an object in ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Now it hasn't the copy property in ARC,so how should I do when I want copy an object?
Then I write a test code:

test.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *str1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *str2;
```

test.m

```
self.str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
self.str2 = [self.str1 copy];
[self.str2 appendString:@"World"];
NSLog(@"str1:%@,str2:%@",self.str1,self.str2);
```

When I run,it got crash:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'
```

So,how should I do?

Comment: Have you tried using `mutableCopy` instead of `copy`?

Comment: Does `[-NSMutableString copy]` really return an immutable string?!

Comment: It works,thank you!It's my carelessness in ARC :)

Comment: @noa: Yes, `copy` always gives you an immutable version.

Answer (score 6):

`copy` should always returns immutable copies of objects, and `mutableCopy` (if available) should always returns mutable objects, regardless of whether the receiver is mutable or immutable. This way, you can be sure that when you ask for a `copy` it *will* be immutable and when you ask for a `mutableCopy` it *will* be mutable.

This concept has been around for years, and is not specific to ARC. ARC simply handles the memory management of objects, not their mutability.